# How prevent facebook not to cache the images?

Tags: facebook, addthis

In my website I use this `meta`

```
<meta property="og:url" content="..." />        
<meta property="og:title" content="..." />  
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="..." />
```

Also I use `addthis` widget.

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" addthis:url="..." addthis:title="..." addthis:description="..." addthis:image="<?php echo $image_url; ?>"> 
<a href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=250&pubid=..." class="addthis_button_compact"><img src="/images/share.png" width="66" height="24" border="0" alt="Share" /></a> 
</div>
```

At first `$image_url` contains the logo of the website, then I changed it to thumbnails that each post contains. When I share the post via facebook it shows the logo, but when I see the source of the code, the image url is the new one. It look likes that facebook has cached the image.
How can I prevent facebook not to cache the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to run your URL through the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) everytime you change some of the `og:meta` tags. This will force Facebook to re-scrape your URL and it will fetch the new images and data. There is no way to prevent Facebook from caching the image - they depend on heavy caching in order to provide better performance.

Here is an extract from [the like button's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) that explains:

> #### When does Facebook scrape my page?
>
> Facebook needs to scrape your page to know how to display it around
>   the site.
>
> Facebook scrapes your page every 24 hours to ensure the properties are
>   up to date. The page is also scraped when an admin for the Open Graph
>   page clicks the Like button and when the URL is entered into the
>   Facebook URL Debugger. Facebook observes cache headers on your URLs -
>   it will look at "Expires" and "Cache-Control" in order of preference.
>   However, even if you specify a longer time, Facebook will scrape your
>   page every 24 hours.
>
> The user agent of the scraper is:
>   `"facebookexternalhit/1.1
>   (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"`

Comment: If possible could you please give the link for this documentation

Comment: @anv - oh yes - certainly! I don't know why I didn't post it before... Check my edits :)